# Redux with React - Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

In my reducer file I have an initial state of shopObject, an array of objects.

```
interface Data {
  shopObject: object[],
}

const initialState = {
  shopObject: <Data['shopObject']>[],
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.SELECTED_SHOP_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        shopObject: [...state.shopObject, action.payload],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The goal is to append each object (which is an item) that I receive into this array so that I can show a list of each item in a shopping cart.
The problem that is happening is when I add an item the application crashes with the error

> Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.

When I `console.log(action.payload)` I can see that it is indeed being passed succesfully.

action.payload

```
{
    "Data": 4,
    "Price": 20,
    "Carrier": "Verizon",
    "Country": "US",
    "Type": "Prepaid",
    "Path": "shop"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks as if you're using TypeScript (if that's correct, please add that tag to your question.)

The typing of your `initialState` variable appears to be incorrect.  It looks like `initialState` should just implement the interface `Data`, like this:

```js
const initialState: Data = {
  shopObject: [],
}
```

You'll also want to type `action`, probably.  [Here's a REPL](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUM5AZwAsB7ABwHkAjAKwgTAC5lS6GwBtAXQBpcAvrlwJSIQmGShgYYHAA2AZUyQWaDFgC8OfETJV2jFj35DcEAB7lSUSQBMI8AK7zJMJyEbAxyABQSMFG1pWQVlQN5kRFkxFmwwAE9yCBYAIhhSUlTI8jgE%20VI4OxY2ekYBAEodAkIAdxkEYj9o7xAAOkTkqrwCAgQ4QhR0zNSmXV7kKAgwJygQaonetuWAyH5F3pIKGjLmZE5lttWII-0djkiWsTbc-MK7PnHegQBuJ4dnVzGNqZm5ohUEDeBCEAiAA) demonstrating the interface change.
More from the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html